# Is it possible not specify the sheet name and columns?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, excel

So, I'm doing a program that it imports an excel file to sql database, and all works fine if I specify the columns of the excel and database columns, and sheet name... Look at my code and after that I will specify more in what is the problem:

```
protected void Upload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string excelPath = Server.MapPath("~/Nova pasta/") + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);

    string filepath = Server.MapPath("~/Nova pasta/") + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
    string filename = Path.GetFileName(filepath);
    FileUpload1.SaveAs(excelPath);
    string ext = Path.GetExtension(filename);

    String strConnection = @"Data Source=PEDRO-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=costumizado;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=1234";
    string excelConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filepath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HRD=YES;IMEX=1;\"";

    OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);

    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * from [rptListaMovs_4$]", excelConnection);

    excelConnection.Open();

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from [rptListaMovs_4$] ", strConnection);

    OleDbDataReader dReader;
    dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(strConnection))
    {
        sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "Dados";
        sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Data Mov", "Data Mov.");
        sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Data Valor", "Data Valor");
        sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Descrição do Movimento", "Descrição do Movimento");
        sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Valor em EUR", "Valor em EUR");

        sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dReader);
    }

    excelConnection.Close();
}
```

Insted of This: `"Select * from [rptListaMovs_4$]"`

I want this: `"Select * from ["+SheetNameWithoutCopyPastHisName+"]"`

And Insted of this

```
sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Data Mov", "Data Mov.");
sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Data Valor", "Data Valor");
sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Descrição do Movimento", "Descrição do Movimento");
sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Valor em EUR", "Valor em EUR");
```

I would like to have something, that it is not necessary to put the columns names, cause sometimes I want to import an excel with different Schema and it doesn't allow me

Comment: `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` makes no sense. You are executing the command correctly later with `dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();`. `ExecuteNonQuery` is for insert, delete, update and DDL statements.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Yeah, Thanks for saying already took out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to get first sheet name with this:

```
DataTable schema = excelConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
string sheetName = schema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
```

As for the field names, this should do the trick:

```
for(int i = 0; i < dReader.FieldCount; i++)
{
    sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add(dReader.GetName(i), dReader.GetName(i));
}
```

Comment: Hey! So to the  sheet name it worked, really well! Thanks but for the fied names it appear this exception "
The specified ColumnMapping does not match any column at the source or destination."

Comment: My experience is that these schema tables are a mess. The available tables and columns names vary from provider to provider. Set a break point on the line `string sheetName = schema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();` and quick watch `schema.Rows[0]`, then drill down the columns collection to see the available column names.